Does de Rham cohomology group always looks like $\mathbb{R}^k$?
I recently learned the de Rham cohomology theory from Loring W. Tu’s An Introduction to Manifolds. The examples of cohomology groups in the book always appear as $\mathbb{R}^k$. This made me wonder if this is a general phenomenon. If true, I could determine the cohomology groups by simply counting the dimensions in the Mayer–Vietoris sequence. I hope someone can help me answer this question. Thank you!

Often, Cohomologies are abelian groups of finite rank or vector spaces of finite dimension. (Their being finite dimension is quite coincidental.) So if you compute the cohomology of real coefficients, they will be the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. However, choosing a basis might not be an easy problem. If you want to identify a vector space to $\mathbb{R}^k$, you need to choose a specific basis of the vector space.

Thanks for your comment!

You are right. The De Rham cohomology groups, when using real coefficients, are not just groups but finite-dimensional real vector spaces, and the only possibilities are then $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Thanks for your answer!

This is not quite true. The vector spaces are only guaranteed to be finite dimensional when the manifold is compact. There are smooth manifolds with infinite dimensional de Rham cohomology groups.

If $X$ is an arbitrary smooth manifold, there is no guarantee that its cohomology groups $H^k(X)$ will be finite dimensional. For example, you can take $X=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Z}^2$ (so not a quotient, but a complement). You can show using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, and induction, that $\dim_\mathbb{R}H^1(X)=\infty$. It is, however, true that all $H^k(X)$ are finite dimensional when $X$ is compact. In practice, this is often what we're interested in.
But even when $X$ is compact, it wouldn't be right to say that you can "determine the cohomology groups by counting dimensions". This only gives very crude information. The cohomology groups encode specific geometric/topological information, and without explicitly identifying the generators of the cohomology group, this information is lost. You can have a look at this question I asked some years ago: Finding generators for cohomology group by analysing Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Once you have determined explicit cohomology classes $\{[\omega_1],\dots,[\omega_{\dim H^k(X)}]\}$ which form a basis for $H^k(X)$, then you have really "determined"  the cohomology group.
Also note that $H^\bullet(X)=\oplus_{k=0}^{\dim X}H^k(X)$ is a (non-commutative) ring, under the wedge product of differential forms. If you want to completely determine the de Rham cohomology of $X$, then you should also know relations between the generators that you have selected. So, again, I don't think it would be correct to say that you can determine the de Rham cohomology from a simple dimension count.
